# Key symbol in notification bar when swiped once on Xperia with Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sony-xperia

I've recently upgraded to Android 5.0 in my Xperia C3. I don't seem to find the user profiles symbol on my notification or any sign of it anywhere. I also see a key symbol on my notification bar near to the battery indicator. What does it mean? And why don't I have the user profile options?

Comment: Are you able to access users via Settings>Users>add user?

Comment: On Nexus devices, the user profile is on the very top-right of the quick settings. As for a key symbol, I'm not really sure as I never see that on Nexus devices. Probably an exclusive to Xperia phones.

Comment: @Thomas Martin : no sir. I dont seem to find it.

Comment: @Andrew.T : I think it's a bug in xperia phones. My phone is not performing good after the update. Also the front camera is very bad. It produces low brightness dull photos. I'm waiting for an update from xperia. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The key symbol indicates that you're connected to a VPN

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the key symbol means, your network is being monitored. If you run "Mobiwol" (a non-root firewall), it creates a VPN.